# Issue in uploading large file (>250mb) only in mozilla?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp, mozilla

I am able to upload large files through chrome, safari, IE but not in Mozilla using ajax post method.

> Error: Post error with status 0

I tried clearing cookies and cache no result. Finally i tried using safe mode mozilla still issue is not solved.

I have gone through the Jquery file upload. But I am new and i have basic knowledge on js and jquery. So I am not able to understand how to integrate to cakephp application and make upload and get response after successful upload.
Is there any other way to upload so that every browser supports upload large files.

Comment: I'm not sure, may this be cache size problem? What is cachce limit size in your settings?

Comment: I modified that too to 1024MB still no result.

Comment: Solution: Everytime I am upoading a file which is greater than 250mb and using firebug console to check status. So here the issue with firebug console, if I open uploading is not working. But with normal developer console no issues. Firebug console is creating issues for uploading large files. But still I am confused why there is no issue with small file upload with firebug console.